# Exporting public aws route53 records as private cloudDNS records

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, cloud, amazon-route53, google-cloud-dns

I want to export some public domain names present in `aws` `route53` and use those in my private network in `CloudDns` in google.

I see one option is to list the records in aws as yaml :

```
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id <zoneID> --output yaml
```

Then export this in google cloud dns as private zone

```
gcloud dns record-sets import -z=EXAMPLE_ZONE_NAME --zone-file-format path-to-example-zone-file --visibility=private
```

Just wondering if this will work and if there is any complexity with this if anyone else has tried.

PS: Not removing/updating aws route53 yet for this, its just a sample to learn.

EDIT: Export using listing of records by aws command as yaml format did not work, so I installed cli53 ( a tool to manage route 53 records)

1. Then exported it using below cli53 command

   cli53 export
2. Later, I tried to import in google cloud using below commands :

gcloud dns managed-zones create private-zone --description="private zone" --visibility=private --dns-name="example.com" --networks=default

3. I tried to import the dns records into cloud dns private zone

   gcloud dns record-sets import -z="private-zone" --zone-file-format  dns_export_cli53_bind_wedev_tools

But this does not import anything and below message is coming on the terminal. There are 4 records other than NS, SOA and alias in the file

"Nothing to do, all the records in "

Comment: If you are trying to learn, then show your results, errors and the config file. Without modifying the config file, it will not work. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks John for the guidance

Comment: You should **not** have `--zone-file-format` in the command line to import zone file in yaml format.

Comment: I had exported the file as BIND format so for that the instruction says to add thsi flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the ns records and @origin at the top. of file , that worked