# Useless error message using --zone-file-format

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, gcloud

Running (all versions, plain+alpha+beta) with the zonefile.txt downloaded from my current DNS provider

```
gcloud dns record-sets import --zone=some-zone-tld --zone-file-format ./zonefile.txt
```

fails with the error:

```
ERROR: gcloud crashed (AttributeError): 'SyntaxError' object has no attribute 'message'
```

any ideas to what that error-message means? Does anyone have a working example zone-file that I can look at?

I have tried this but it made no difference to the error message: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65204476/1151537

this is the zonefile:

```
$ORIGIN intellifinder.de.
;A records
*.intellifinder.de. IN  1h  A   35.244.179.110
mail.intellifinder.de.  IN  1h  A   35.244.179.110
www.intellifinder.de.   IN  1h  A   35.244.179.110
api.intellifinder.de.   IN  1h  A   35.227.215.119
cloud.intellifinder.de. IN  1h  A   35.227.253.17
intellifinder.de.   IN  1m  A   93.191.155.240

;MX records
intellifinder.de.   IN  1h  MX  10  intellifinder-de.mail.protection.outlook.com.

;SOA records
@   IN  1h  SOA ns3.dandomain.dk.   hostmaster@dandomain.dk 2021082300  1h  1h  2w  5m
```

Comment: I tried the gcloud feedback command, it opened a browser window with an error message: "Bad Request
Error 400"

Comment: How do you think anyone can help you without even seeing the zonefile you are attempting to use. There is probably a problem in it and then a bug in `gcloud` that is unable to format the error message properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message means that **the syntax inside the text file is not well defined**.

You can check more information about importing records [here](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/records#importing_and_exporting_record_sets).

The issue might also be related to **gcloud shell**, to confirm that, try to import the files again but with the --verbosity flag on the [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference#--verbosity).

Have a look at this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/issues/58905) where the same error was reported.

Comment: --verbosity=debug pointed to TTL: "DNS TTL value is not well-formed". Tried different values to no avail. Tried exporting from GCP and found out the TTL goes before IN, not after. The zonefile I exported from my current provider was broken.